# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'instancemethod' and 'int'

Tags: python

I am trying to debug some Python (with next to zero knowledge of the language). In some code, there is a line:

```
self.min_spread = self.exchange.account.get_fee * 2
```

This returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "launch.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "launch.py", line 28, in main
    bot = marketmaker.MarketMaker(exchange, pair)
  File "T:\mm-1.01\src\strategies\marketmaker.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.min_spread = self.exchange.account.get_fee * 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'instancemethod' and 'int'
```

After some research, I added parentheses after get_fee, but this had no effect. What is wrong?

This is Python 2.7.

Edit:

Just to clarify, if I add parentheses, the error becomes:

```
  File "T:\mm-1.01\src\strategies\marketmaker.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.min_spread = self.exchange.account.get_fee() * 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'instancemethod' and 'int'
```

Edit:

Here is the account class:

```
class Account():


    def __init__(self, agent):
        self.agent = agent
        self._account()

    def _account(self):
        pass

    def get_balance(self):
        self._update_balance()
        return self.balance

    def get_fee(self):
        return self.get_fee

    def get_open_orders(self):
        self._update_open_orders()
        return self.open_orders

    def cancel(self, order_id):
        pass

    def cancel_all(self, order_type='all'):
        if order_type == 'all':
            for order in self.get_open_orders():
                self.cancel(order['order_id'])
        else:
            for order in self.get_open_orders():
                if order['type'] == order_type:
                    self.cancel(order['order_id'])
```

Comment: Doesn't `self.exchange.account.get_fee()` need any input?

Comment: Post your entire class. Otherwise its hard to tell, because your function might require arguments.

Comment: I don't think so, although I'm out of my depth here as I don't speak Python. The method doesn't make sense to me (C# dev), it is defined as def get_fee(self):
            return self.get_fee

Comment: oh my, the instancemethod is returning itself. That's your problem. It should return a float. Maybe the programmer meant def get_fee(self): return self.fee ..instead

Comment: @RBT how about making another class which exactly mimics your so *`classified and personal`* class

Comment: I've posted the Account class.

Comment: It lacks implementation.

Comment: It seems as though someone wasn't finished defining that class. as @Leifingson said, the method returns itself, that can't be a good thing. However, looking at the rest of the code, `return self.get_fee` should've been something along the line of `return self.fee`. Seeing as there is no variable named fee, i say, back to the developer with this piece! ;)

Comment: Yes, I'm going to park this. Would you believe I paid money for this??

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you forgot to add the `()` after the function call, so:

```
self.exchange.account.get_fee() * 2
```

After some further research it seems that your function itself has a problem:

```
def get_fee(self):
    return self.get_fee
```

Now it returns `self.get_fee` which is an instance method, it does not return any value. This is why you're getting an error.

Comment: @KDawG Then this requires more research. We will need to see the whole class.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've posted the Account class.

Comment: @RBT Where is the the line `self.exchange.account.get_fee()`?

Comment: I'm parking this. This is a bot that I bought yesterday, but it's not fit for purpose.